# Some programs do not run with the .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: .net-framework

I have installed the Camtasia Studio 8 video editor on my notebook and have always used it without any problem. I recently started studying the C # programming language and needed to install the latest version of the .NET Framework (version 4.8), the problem is that I can't run Camtasia Studio and some other programs anymore.

[image: Camtasia doesn't run]

I did a lot of research on the Internet and the solution to run the program again was to downgrade the .NET Framework to version 4.0, but I still want to use the latest version of the .NET Framework for my C# studies.

I talked to a user on Stack Overflow In Portuguese about this problem and he mentioned something about enabling .NET 3.5.1 in the "windows features" panel. Below is an image of my panel:

[image: Windows features panel]

He also told me to ask this question here in this community, and here I am. I would like to know how I can run my programs with .NET Framework 4.8 or another more up-to-date version (if released).

I have already tried to run the program in compatibility mode with Windows 7 and also tried to run in administrator mode.

The version of Camtasia I have installed is 8 but I am also unable to run the Camtasia Studio 9 installer after installing .NET Framework 4.8.

I am using Windows 7 Pro 64 bits.

Comment: Instead of trying to fix this yourself, contact TechSmith Support.

Comment: Which the Camtasia's version? Please, adds it on the post.

Comment: Do mention what's the Windows Version you have on your laptop. Just check if there's anything getting recorded in the Windows Event Viewer under Application tab. It might tell you the exe or dll or any other dependency that's causing the crash. This might be useful in communicating with TechSmith. also just as an experiment, try uninstalling Camtasia, create a new Admin user and reinstall when logged in under that user and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: On my Windows 7 64 SP1 with April-2016 roll up updates, I could not replicate this issue. Camtasia 8.0.6 ran without any issues even after installing Dot Net 4.8. Is your Windows 7 64 (It should be SP1) up-to-date? As per this link https://support.techsmith.com/hc/en-us/articles/219908907-Windows-Support-Matrix   Windows 7 should support Camtasia v6 thru v2019. As already stated by @Ramhound , Dot Net v4.8 should be backward compatible with 4.0. Also try Clean Boot approach and see if that makes any difference. Just to rule out any other third-party service conflicting with this app somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I have Camtasia V2020 installed here and it works fine with the newest version of .NET Framework.  You need to update Camtasia as your version is quite old.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how I can run my programs with .NET Framework 4.8 or another more up-to-date version (if released).

It should be as simple as installing .NET Framework 4.8 on your system.  .NET Framework 4.8 only supports Windows 7, if the Windows 7 Service Pack 1 is installed, Windows 7 RTM is not supported.

Source: [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 offline installer for Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4503548/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-offline-installer-for-windows)

> I did a lot of research on the Internet and the solution to run the program again was to downgrade the .NET Framework to version 4.0, but I still want to use the latest version of the .NET Framework for my C# studies.

.NET Framework 4.8 replaces .any NET Framework 4.x version that is installed on your system.  It is not possible to have .NET Framework 4.0 and .NET Framework 4.8 installed on the same system.

> I talked to a user on Stack Overflow In Portuguese about this problem and he mentioned something about enabling .NET 3.5.1 in the "windows features" panel.

Enabling .NET Framework 3.5 will not solve your problem for multiple reasons.  The primary reasons is that unless Camtasia Studio 8 requires .NET Framework 3.5 instead of .NET Framework 4.0 then it doesn't resolve your actual problem.  In fact, anyone indicating you should enable .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 on Windows 7, is suggesting an action that cannot actually be performed.  **Windows 7 already has .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 installed.**  The user who suggested, you enable .NET Framework 3.5, clearly did not understand you were running Windows 7.

You need to contact TechSmith Support to determine the reason Camtasia Studio 8 and Camtasia 9 is crashing when you have .NET Framework 4.8 installed.  The application absolutely should NOT crash when .NET Framework 4.8 is installed.  **The .NET Framework 4.8 is backwards compatible with .NET Framework 4.0 applications.**

However, if the application can specifically indicate it only supports a specific version, and that might be the cause of the crash.

Comment: I don't agree with the suggestion that you upgrade to a newer version, since that is not a free option, there is the additional concern I have due to the fact the system requirements for Camtasisa 2020 doesn't specifically indicate Windows 7 support.  **By contacting TechSmith support you will be able to confirm, from a authoritative source, if the application actually can ran with .NET Framework 4.8 installed or not.

Comment: I am going under the assumption you are running Windows 7.  There are multiple reasons for this, the primary reason, you indicated you installed .NET Framework 4.8.  If you were running Windows 10, then that particular version, is built-into Windows 10 version 1909.  **If this is not the case you should edit your question to clarify what operating system you actually are using.** If actually have Windows 10 version 1909 installed my answer will change dramatically.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Pro 64x

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 - I will have to assume you have the Windows 7 Service Pack 1 installed otherwise you wouldn't have been able to install the .NET Framework 4.8 using the offline installer

Comment: Yes, i have SP1 installed here